# Grails RemoteFunction creates bad javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, dojo

I am taking over a project from an engineer that left my company, and am having to quickly come up to speed on Grails, so if this is a noob question, well, I'm a noob.

In one of one of my GSP files, I've got a remoteFunction call in the middle of a javaScript function:

```
function fnCreateEntitiesPerForceChart() {
      var interval = $("#entitiesPerForceTimeIntervalSelect").val();
      var url = '${createLink(controller: 'federation', action: 'createEntitiesPerForceChart')}?interval='+escape(interval);
      $("#entitiesPerForceChart").attr("src", url);

      ${remoteFunction(controller: 'federation', 
        action: 'getEntitiesPerForceTable', 
        params: '\'interval=\'+interval', 
        onSuccess: 'fnUpdateEntitiesPerForceTable(data,textStatus)')}; 
    }
```

That remoteFunction call is being sent to the client as:

```
try{DojoGrailsSpinner.show();}catch(e){} dojo.xhr('Get',{content:{'interval='+interval}, preventCache:true, url:'/FederationReporter/federation/getEntitiesPerForceTable', load:function(response){ fnUpdateEntitiesPerForceTable(data,textStatus); }, handle:function(response,ioargs){try{DojoGrailsSpinner.hide();}catch(e){} }, error:function(error,ioargs){try{DojoGrailsSpinner.hide();}catch(e){} } });;
```

Which is causing a error:
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
...){} dojo.xhr('Get',{content:{'interval='**+**interval}, preventCache:true, url:'/Fed...

federation (line 400, col 60) (which is the bolded '+' before the second 'interval'

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo `content` should be a key-value pair.

`{content:{'interval': interval}`

Comment: Okay, but how do I change the remotefunction call so that a better dojo line is generated?

Comment: Changed my params line to params: '\'interval\''+':'+interval and it gave me a valid content pair.  Thanks!

Comment: This time the problem was indeed on your code. If you want to change the remoteFunction call or whatever is provided by the grails dojo plugin, you will have to fork the project at https://github.com/cfxram/grails-dojo and use your fork instead.